# SWreveal - how to go back to the view controller I started with

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWReveal. Everything works fine except that I would like to be able to go back to the view controller from which I fired the sidebar.

For example, let's assume I have 2 view controllers: VC1 and VC2.

I'm on VC1. I open the sidebar and select the option to move to VC2. I then want to move back to VC1 but not via the sidebar (imagine that VC2 is a settings page that is applied to a table on VC1 - I do not want to have a button on a tool bar for the odd occasion I am going to use this functionality so I'd rather it lived in a sidebar menu).

If I was not using a sidebar menu, a simple segue from VC1 to VC2 via a button would enable me to use the 'back' button.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of behaviour with SWReveal sidebar menu?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my application first i add a segue to the main menu of type modal with identifier then in the prepare for segue i put that code

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"backtologin"]) {

    MWViewController *controller = (MWViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


}
```